# Break out of ruby inner block using catch/throw

Tags: ruby, exception

I am interested in breaking out of both the outer and inner block if an exception is thrown in an inner ruby block. The code might look something like this:

```
catch "ExitBlock" do
      foo.each_with_index do |el, idx|
        bar = ... // do more stuff, 
        bar.each_with_index do |el1, idx1|
          if some_bad_stuff
            throw "ExitBlock"
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

if some_bad_stuff is true, it should exit both the outer block and the inner block, not just the inner block. the code above is giving me an ArgumentError however with:

`ArgumentError: uncaught throw "ExitBlock"`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with symbols:

```
catch :exit_block do
  foo.each_with_index do |el, idx|
    bar = ... // do more stuff, 
    bar.each_with_index do |el1, idx1|
      if some_bad_stuff
        throw :exit_block
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But the documentation says *["[argument] can be an arbitrary object, not only Symbol"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-catch)*

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: agreed! I was using strings and it would break me. I'd have to look at the source. with symbols it works just fine.

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you using? `throw`ing and `catch`ing arbitrary objects was only added in 1.9.0, before that you could only `throw` and `catch` `Symbol`s.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much cleaner to just break out of the loop rather than bringing exceptions into the mix:

```
foo.each_with_index do |el, idx|
    bar = ... // do more stuff, 
    break_outer = false
    bar.each_with_index do |el1, idx1|
        if some_bad_stuff
            break_outer = true
            break
        end
    end
    if break_outer
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: This is bad. It will only break out of the inner block. If you read the original post, it specifically mentions that the requirement is to break out of both blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the inner loop. Fixing.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the down vote for your edit. I still think the catch/throw solution is cleaner than adding this additional state, though. Also, if you need to nest even further, this will become more difficult to follow and maintain.

Comment: I disagree with using exceptions for control flow like this. I don't know about Ruby, specifically, but usually exceptions are a significant performance hit and should be saved for those truly exceptional cases. I guess it depends on how likely the `some_bad_stuff` is to happen but since it's possible to write this without exceptions that's how I would do it. Additional nesting would decrease some readability with this solution but there might also be ways to avoid too many nested loops.

Comment: @pizen, `throw` and `catch` have nothing to do with exceptions in Ruby, it's purely to unwind call stack and pass some value down below, aimed at those recursive algorithms